# Customizing Navbar collapse button when hover

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to remove the background of the collapse button when the mouse hover to the button. here is the picture. I really want to remove that white background when mouse hover to that button please help me. Im new to html and css and also to bootstrap.

[image]

Here is my html code

```
          <nav class ="navbar navbar-default" role= "navigation">
    <div class = "container">
        <div class ="navbar-header">
            <button type ="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#nav-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar" ></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>  
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-collapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="index.html">Students</a></li>
              <li class="nav-divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Faculty</a></li>
              <li class="nav-divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
              <li class="nav-divider"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
              <li class="nav-divider"></li>

            </ul>
       </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

Here is my css code.

```
        #fot{ position:fixed;
        bottom:0;
        } 
      .navbar-default{
       background-color:rgb(193,57,45);

       }
       .navbar .nav > li > a{
       color:#ffe6e6;
       }
      .navbar .nav > li > a:hover{
      color:#000000;
      }
    .navbar .nav .active > a{
    background-color:rgb(193,57,45);
    color:#000000;
    }
   .navbar .nav .active > a:hover{
    background:none;
    color:#fff;
    }
   .nav .nav-divider{
    height: 50px;
   margin: 0 10px;
   border-right: 1px solid #a92419;
   border-left: 1px solid #c1392d;
   }
  @media(max-width: 768px) 
  {
 .nav .nav-divider{
 height: 1px;
  margin: 0 10px;
    background-color:#a92419;   
    }


   .navbar-default .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background-color: #fff;
     margin:0 0 4px;
    width: 25px;
    height: 5px;

    }
  button.navbar-toggle{
  background:none;
  border:none;
  color:#000;

   }
  .navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
  border-color: #a92419; 
  } 
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the background-color for both `hover` as well as `focus`.
You can do that by adding this to your CSS:

```
.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus, .navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover {
    background: none;
}
```

Here's a jsFiddle with the above code: https://jsfiddle.net/AndrewL32/mowb6gcb/

Comment: It's working :) Why so many class is called there sir? can you tell me why?

Comment: The reason the grey color is popping up everytime you interact with the button is because bootstrap has a standard grey background css property added for it. The above classes over-ride that default property Tikboy.

Comment: `.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:focus` removes the grey color when you hover over the button and `.navbar-default .navbar-toggle:hover` removes the grey color when you interact with the button.

Comment: Thank you again sir :) Goodluck to your carrer :)

Comment: Same with yours :)

Comment: Im just only a student tho but next time i'm the one who will answer your question :)

Answer (score 0):

use this css which works on hover

```
button.navbar-toggle:hover{
  background:none;
  /* other css as you requirment*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal, straight forward way, using the psuedo class `:hover` to add a css style to items upon hovering the mouse over them

```
button.navbar-toggle {
    background: #ccc; //a gray background as default
}


button.navbar-toggle:hover {
    background: none; //no background when you hover over the button
}
```

Comment: The answer you marked as correct explains it perfectly, and I didn't consider it. Bootstrap has a CSS file of its own. And in the bootstrap css it has a style rule for the  ":focus" psuedo class. So you need to overwrite the ":focus" class. If you don't want that gray background on the button in general then you can consider removing the rule from the twitter-bootstrap css file

Comment: Thankyou very much sir for explaining :)